# Magento2.1.9 Cart rules configuration -discount for all items when I expect only for items which fulfill the conditions

Tags: php, cart, rule, magento2.1

I have a problem with the cart rule configuration.
Although I set the rule for a particular category, if one item fulfills the condition -the discount is for all items even from other categories and those that do not meet the conditions.

[Conditions configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqCQc.png)

For one item this configuration works correctly

[First item of conditions category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1Csv.png)

Here I expect discount only for the first item, but:

[Secound item is from this same category but qty is less than 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z65MC.png)

..and when I added to cart product from another category, but minimum one item fulfilled the conditions -last product also has discount.. :/

[Other which is not in my conditions configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cfuq.png)

I expect in the discount cart only for items that meet the conditions.

Do you have any ideas what do I do wrong? Is this a mistake on the Magento side? If so, how can I fix it on the back-end?

Thanks :)

Edit:
Part of action

[Action part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58AS3.png)

Comment: can you show me action part?

Comment: I added image with actions part

Comment: you want condition like qty greate than 3 and less than 20 right?

Comment: Yes, for some category, but Magento gives discount for all items when one item fullfills conditions

Comment: Now I see that this configuration is for sum all qty of items in cart... Is  maybe some way for settings conditions per item? For example: if item meets conditions it will give discount, if not -it will not give... ?

Comment: i think it take all quantity for cart

Comment: I know, but I need discount only for items which met conditions -not discount for all items. Any ideas?

Comment: you need to customize it